# .htaccess redirect issue with language modifier and different backend redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here are some examples of what I want to do:

```
www.example.de --> https://www.example.de/de/index
http://www.example.de -->https://www.example.de/de/index
https://www.example.de -->https://www.example.de/de/index
```

I'm doing that with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/de/index  [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.de
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.de/de/index [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

However, I am stuck on those conditions:

```
(http(s)://)www.example.de/ANYSTRING --> https://www.example.de/de/index
(http(s)://)www.example.de/(anything not de or en)/ANYSTRING --> https://www.example.de/de/index
```

I also have a backend which can look like this:
https://www.example.de/backend/manage-stuff.php

This should also have the language modifier included, can't figure out how that should be possible. Any hint is highly appreciated.

//EDIT

Some more examples for clarification:

```
https://www.example.de/anything (not backend) --> https://www.example.de/de/index
https://www.example.de/en/anything --> https://www.example.de/en/index
https://www.example.de/de/anything --> https://www.example.de/de/index
https://www.example.de/backend --> https://www.example.de/de/backend
https://www.example.de/anything/backend --> https://www.example.de/de/backend
```

The JS/CSS files are loaded like this https://www.example.de/inc/template/temp3/js/jsfile.js the mod_rewrite should possibly not break that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en|de) https://www.example.de/$1/index [R=301,L]

RewriteRule (?:^|/)(backend)(?:/|$) https://www.example.de/de/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(?!backend|en|de). https://www.example.de/de/index [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That leads to a redirect loop: [link](https://www.example.de/de/index?lang=de&page=index&lang=de&page=index&lang=de&page=index&lang=de&page=index&lang=de&page=index&lang=de...)

Comment: we are getting closer, but /en/index is also allowed and /en_OR_de/backend as well. In addition /backend should go to /de/backend

Comment: everything should be redirected to https. Valid formats are /de/index -- /en/index -- de/backend -- en/backend. I am also getting strange errors with my js inclusions? Invalid are /index (should go to de/index) or /backend (should go to de/backend/. EVERYTHING else is /de/index (except for the js/css stuff?!)

Comment: I am getting confused with these comments that's why I suggest editing the question and clarify all of these cases.

Comment: ok, here is the thing now: /de/backend goes to de/index/ which is wrong, AND, all my js files which are included like this `<script src="https://www.example.de/inc/template/template_v3/js/marker.js"></script>` are broken... css are fine though... Thank you for everything so far, really appreciate it...

Comment: I will have to to stop supporting this as this is becoming way too broad. If you can break it down to one problem per question then I can answer it.